# Finding strings that do not include specific patterns in Lua

Tags: string, lua, substring, lua-patterns

(Sorry if the title is vague, I couldn't figure out a way to summarize this properly even though the problem itself is easy).

Say I have a Lua string like this:
`s = "dog frog bag bog cat shop hog"` and I want to get a substring from it that only includes those words that do not include the letter "a". How would I go about doing this?

Comment: `for w in s:gmatch"%f[%a][^a%A]*%f[%A]" do print(w) end`

Comment: `t = s:gsub("[a-z]*a[a-z]*","")`